# ValueError: Cannot convert <JIRA Status: name='Close', id='6'> to Excel

Tags: python, excel, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to automate the service desk reports on a monthly basis from JIRA fetching the details from the JIRA API such as:
1. Ticket number (key)
2. Summary
3. Description
4. Some custom fields (such as organizations)
5. Created Date
6. Updated Date
7. Status
8. Priority

I'm using the python JIRA and openpyxl libraries to work with the jira functions and writing the reports to an excel sheet (planning to make this run through a cronjob later on a particular time basis of a month)

The issue I'm facing is I am able to get the values from the 1 to 6 but gets stuck at 7 and 8. 
The reason is I'm expecting values for example:

- for status -  'Close' or 'Waiting for Customer' etc

But what I get is: name='Close', id='6'

- for priority I expect - 'Low' or 'High

But what I get is: name='Low', id='4'

Because of this when the code tries to write to an excel it throws an error like:

```
in _bind_value
raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
ValueError: Cannot convert <JIRA Priority: name='Low', id='4'> to Excel

in _bind_value
raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
ValueError: Cannot convert <JIRA Status: name='Close', id='6'> to Excel
```

This is an example of the code I currently have (it's fairly straightforward):

```
issues_in_project = jira.search_issues('project = ASD AND assignee in (membersOf(jira-users)))

for issue in issues_in_project:
    key_list.append(issue.key)
    status_list.append(issue.fields.status)
    priority_list.append(issue.fields.priority)

for key in key_list:
    ws.cell(row=key_row, column=start_column).value = key
    key_row += 1

for status in status_list:
    ws.cell(row=status_row, column=start_column+1).value = status
    status_row += 1

for priority in priority_list:
    ws.cell(row=priority_row+1,column=start_column+2).value = priority
    priority_row+=1
```

The key values which are the ticket numbers are received fine.

Is there any way to obtain only the values through JIRA API like for ex for Status: Close and for Priority: Low and avoid the id values coming in (as shown above) with the values I really intend to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the attributes on the issue are objects, such as `priority` and `status`. Notice the error message mentions the following:

```
<JIRA Priority: name='Low', id='4'>
```

and

```
<JIRA Status: name='Close', id='6'>
```

Those are string representations of the attributes. They're telling you what their type is (`Priority` or `Status`) and that they both have certain attributes such as `name` and `id`.

The `name` attribute is what you want, so you need to access it on the `status` and `priority` objects like this:

```
ws.cell(row=status_row, column=start_column+1).value = status.name
```

and

```
ws.cell(row=priority_row+1,column=start_column+2).value = priority.name
```

Comment: Thanks a Ton!!. Was a coincidence I just gave that a try and then saw your answer and was matching. It was a great help to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.name` at the end as shown in the code below. This will retrieve only the name part from the values.

```
for status in status_list:
    ws.cell(row=status_row, column=start_column+1).value = status.name
    status_row += 1

for priority in priority_list:
    ws.cell(row=priority_row+1,column=start_column+2).value = priority.name
    priority_row+=1
```

Answer (score -3):

In my case, the error was shown in a custom field, and to solve it I used:

```
for dep in depart_list:
    ws.cell(row=depart_row, column=start_column+2).value = f"{dep}"
    depart_row += 1
```